Apache Lucene indexing strategy to handle large dataset on windows in desktop environment
I do have data divided into 60 sqlite database files. Each database represent a city. Number of rows is different in each database but schema is exactly same with total number of fields are 12. Out of 12, 8 will take part in the search. Total size is around ~20 GB and number of rows combining all databases is ~1.5M. I have to create a GUI and implement full text search on the data. The most important feature is the ability to search in either one or many or all the cities together.
I am using PyLucene and PySide. This is the first time I am trying my hands on with Lucene and looking for the correct way to implement for the above scenario. Here is a solution based on MultiReader
# List to hold IndexReaders
readers = []

dir1 = NIOFSDirectory(Paths.get("database/city1"))
readers.append(DirectoryReader.open(dir1))

dir2 = NIOFSDirectory(Paths.get("database/city2"))
readers.append(DirectoryReader.open(dir2))

# Create MultiReader with the collected readers
multi_reader = MultiReader(readers)

# Create an IndexSearcher
searcher = IndexSearcher(multi_reader)

On a very small test data, this is working fairly but I have no idea whether it would be the right choice for the requirement.

You can try your approach for yourself, using a larger dataset (why not even use the entire dataset - what is stopping you?). Also try using the approach presented in the official Lucene documentation (adapted for PyLucene, of course). Their approach to reading multiple source files in one location only requires one reader.

Compare the results from the above two approaches. If you need to, you can ask a much more specific question about any specific problem you encounter - after first checking if there is already an answer on SO.
